# Question regarding hard coding and making MIDI events

Tags: midi

I am currently working on a project to modify a MIDI song and make it longer, as well as change some instruments and the speed. One of the requirements for the project is as follows:

"Do not make a long list of hard-coded Midi event. You need to change the setMidiEvents method to add additional groups of Midi events programmatically."

I do not understand this requirement. Hard coding is when code is unchanging and stays the same throughout the program, and it says to not make a long list, so I assumed that meant to not add onto the long list of midiEvents. However, the requirement also states that I need to change the setMidiEvents method to add more groups of Midi events, which is the method with the long list included. So am I supposed to create an entirely new Midi event with the private void addMidiEvent? Or simply add onto the setMidiEvents list? Sorry for the dumb question but I just want to be clear about this before I begin coding.

Below is the example that was given to us to change.

Code used as an example: https://github.com/ksnortum/midi-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snortum/play/midi/PlaySequencer.java

```
/**
 * Plays "Mary Had a Little Lamb" on the default software sequencer by
 * constructing each MIDI event by hand.
 * 
 * @author Knute Snortum
 * @version 2017-06-27
 */
public class PlaySequencer {

    /** 
     * To use a specific sequencer, you can run {@link MidiDeviceDisplay} to
     * discover the names of other sequencers on your system.
     * 
     * @see KeyboardToSynth
     */
    private static final String SEQ_DEV_NAME = "default";
    private static final String SEQ_PROP_KEY = "javax.sound.midi.Sequence";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PlaySequencer().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        
        // Get default sequencer, if it exists
        Sequencer sequencer = getSequencer();

        if (sequencer == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            sequencer.open();
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(144.0f);

        // Input MIDI data
        try {
            sequencer.setSequence(getMidiInputData());
        } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Play sequence
        // Sleep, or first note is too long
        sleep(200);
        sequencer.start();

        while (sequencer.isRunning()) {
            sleep(1000);
        }

        // Sleep or last note is clipped
        sleep(200);
        sequencer.close();
    }

    // Create a sequence and set all MIDI events
    private Sequence getMidiInputData() {
        int ticksPerQuarterNote = 4;
        Sequence seq;
        try {
            seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, ticksPerQuarterNote);
            setMidiEvents(seq.createTrack());
        } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return seq;
    }

    // Set MIDI events to play "Mary Had a Little Lamb"
    private void setMidiEvents(Track track) {
        int channel = 0;
        int velocity = 64;
        int note = 61;
        int tick = 0;
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, note, velocity, tick);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, channel, note, 0, tick + 3);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, note - 2, velocity, tick + 4);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, channel, note - 2, 0, tick + 7);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, note - 4, velocity, tick + 8);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, channel, note - 4, 0, tick + 11);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, note - 2, velocity, tick + 12);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, channel, note - 2, 0, tick + 15);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, note, velocity, tick + 16);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, channel, note, 0, tick + 19);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, note, velocity, tick + 20);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, channel, note, 0, tick + 23);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, note, velocity, tick + 24);
        addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, channel, note, 0, tick + 31);
    }

    // Create a MIDI event and add it to the track
    private void addMidiEvent(Track track, int command, int channel, int data1,
            int data2, int tick) {
        ShortMessage message = new ShortMessage();
        try {
            message.setMessage(command, channel, data1, data2);
        } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        track.add(new MidiEvent(message, tick));
    }

    /**
     * @return a specific sequencer object by setting the system property,
     *         otherwise the default
     */
    private Sequencer getSequencer() {
        if (!SEQ_DEV_NAME.isEmpty()
                || !"default".equalsIgnoreCase(SEQ_DEV_NAME)) {
            System.setProperty(SEQ_PROP_KEY, SEQ_DEV_NAME);
        }

        try {
            return MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
            System.err.println("Error getting sequencer");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void sleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to make the song longer is, in the `setMidiEvents()` method, to introduce a scale parameter which changes the actual tick position of each note.

```
addMidiEvent(track, ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, channel, note, 0, scale * (tick + 3));
```

If scale is 1, you get your original song. If scale is 2 song will be twice longer (or tempo will feel twice slower).